# lucene 4.10.2 calculate tf-idf for all terms in index

Tags: java, lucene, tf-idf

I would like to calculate the term frequency and the inverse document frequency (tf-idf) for all terms in index,

I couldn't find any example how to do it with latest Lucene (4.x.x).

Could you help me?

Comment: i will use lucene for indexing xml documents (content only) i would calculat tf-id and use them in classification of documents collection by Kohonen network

Answer (score 2):

To iterate through terms in the index, you'll want to use [`Fields`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/Fields.html) and [`Terms`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/Terms.html).  `Terms` exposes the `docfreq()` for your idf calculation.  Of course, `IndexReader` itself exposes the `numDocs()`.  You can use `DefaultSimilarity.idf` to perform the calculations for you, rather than rolling your own.

```
DefaultSimilarity similarity = new DefaultSimilarity();
int docnum = reader.numDocs();
Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
for (String field : fields) {
    Terms terms = fields.terms(field);
    TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);
    while (termsEnum.next() != null) {
        double idf = similarity.idf(termsEnum.docFreq(), docnum);
        System.out.println("" + field + ":" + termsEnum.term().utf8ToString() + " idf=" + idf);
    }
}
```

tf is only relevant to the term with regards to *a specific document*, so not quite sure what you are looking for there.

Comment: thanks is very useful
how can i use it for a singl field FIELD_CONTENT ( i have 3 fields FIELD_CONTENT,FILE_NAME,PATH)

Comment: Instead of iterating through the field names in a for loop, just pass your known field name into `fields.terms()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String field : fields)
{ 
if( field.equals("contents") )
 { 
 Terms terms = fields.terms(field);
    TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);

 while (termsEnum.next() != null)  
        {

           // double idf = similarity.idf(termsEnum.docFreq(), docnum);

            double idf = Math.log(docnum  / termsEnum.docFreq()); // idf = log(D/dt)

            System.out.println("" + field + ":" + termsEnum.term().utf8ToString() +" fr = "+termsEnum.docFreq() + " idf=" + idf);
        }
   }
     else 
    {
     System.out.println("fin");
    }
      }
```

because idf(t, D) =  log (N \ (d in D: t in d))

N: total number of documents in the corpus

d in D: t in d : number of documents where the term  t  appears